# Job title of a person who checks invitations at a gala function such as a ball.

Tags: single-word-requests

They might also announce a guest's arrival. Not security, although they may have security working for them. Not uniformed but rather dressed appropriately to the function eg black tie.

Comment: Host? Greeter? Front of house? Maitre d'?

Comment: In a club or a less formal occasion, they would be a 'bouncer'

Comment: Thanks for the acceptance!  If you get a better answer, I won't mind if you reverse the acceptance.  At the level of society where people have social secretaries the social secretaries are powerful people.  See, for example this story from the [Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/reliable-source/wp/2015/08/01/embassy-social-secretaries-welcome-deesha-dyer-to-the-club/?utm_term=.992f0e2ed222).

Comment: Yes, maître d' sounds about right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the higher levels of society, this job is the responsibility of the hosts' ***social secretary*** or one of her assistants.

One White House social secretary failed to do or delegate this job properly, and, early in the Obama administration, two uninvited people crashed a state dinner, and were undetected as gate-crashers for several hours.

Earlier, the job of checking the arrivals against the list of invitees was filled by an assistant of the social secretary called "assistant for arrangements", but she claimed that her job had been downgraded by the social secretary at the time of the infamous incident.

This is all described in the [ABC article](http://abcnews.go.com/Politics/white-house-party-crashers-michaele-tareq-salahi-wh/story?id=9210213) *Where were the White House Bouncers?*

One has to go down the social scale from The White House before someone actually called a bouncer would handle the job, although a member of the security staff might be called in if the gate crasher did not leave immediately.

Comment: Thank you. I know it's not a doorman or bouncer because I worked as one for almost twenty years. That is exactly the position I'm talking about, I was hoping it had a fancier title though, perhaps something in French. It is, however, a minor detail though in the grand scheme of things. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking that "doorman" would serve your purposes.  I can't think of the equivalent for a female.

Here is an example from a google books search:
Trial By Fire: Every Soul Makes a Choice - Google Books Result
https://books.google.com/books?isbn=0989317153
M. Scott Snelten - 2013 - ‎Fiction
“Hey, you have to check out the tricked out carriage,” said Mingo. Not to be outdone, a long, ... **The next guests handed the doorman their invitations. Upon closer ...**

Answer (score 1):

"Herald" or "Lord Stewart" ... I totally looked up for this answer from this other forum. Can we post a link here? It's my first time to use Stack Exchange and this is my first answer. Anyway, read more here: http://absolutewrite.com/forums/showthread.php?97832-What-is-the-name-of-this-royal-court-person

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it is better to [include the essential parts of the answer here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259), and provide the link for [reference](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).